# Find quantity sold of particular size over time

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet where I am recording sales of shorts over time. I have been using it to keep a record of who buys them, what date, what size and how many pairs they bought. I'm hoping to expand this to start recording how many of each size have been sold over time.

This is an extract of what I have so far:

[image: size and quantity sold]

In column E, I have used `=COUNTIF(A2:A11,"S")` to count the number of sales of, for example, Small. This is working well. However, I am not at all sure what to put in the, 'By size: Qty,' column (column F from the screenshot).

Is there a formula that will check for all occurrences of a certain value and then check the values in the cells beside what it finds, totaling these values?

Comment: take a look at `SUMIF` https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column E you've used

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A11,"S")
```

To follow that up you want to use SUMIF in column F

```
=SUMIF(A2:A11, "S", B2:B11)
```

The way this works is it looks in column A to find rows that are "S" and then it sums the relevent values from column B.

Comment: Hi @RickyTilson. Thanks for your helpful answer. It was just what I was after.